# Servlet issue - Resource not available

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

So, i have always had this issue, i never understood how servlets work, i constantly get the same error with all off my java ee proojects..

I think this is a issue with my web.xml but i am not sure.

Web XML -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Register-Signup</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>club.xxx.linxer.SignUp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Register-Signup</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Servlet Code -

```java
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("WORKS!");

    }
```

my form code

```html
<form class="modal-content" action="Register" method="post">
```

Error message -

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Linxer_war_exploded/ud/signup/Register
type Status report

message /Linxer_war_exploded/ud/signup/Register

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M9
```

[PROJECT STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9TTo.png)

Comment: Is your war deployed below tomcat/webapps ? Is there a file here in `club.xxx.linxer.SignUp`  Is there any errors in catalina.out?  Does your servlet extend `HttpServlet` .  Also not sure why your method is protected

Comment: I am using localhost to test, and yes there is a Servlet Class there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your action tag should be like `action="Linxer_war_exploded/Register"`.

If you are using jsp then you can write

```
action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Register"
```

to make it dynamic.